# Python Excel - OpenPyxl Limitation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I recently started to automate a report at work using Python. Since my data was provided to me in the form of an excel sheet, I felt the best way to do this was to use an excel python module. My module of choice was [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/). It worked great, I've used it to perform calculations and organise my data ready to plot charts. Now here's the problem...

I know that you cannot update existing charts using openpyxl so that option went out the window.

What I then tried to do was link the data in my openpyxl spreadsheet to another spreadsheet containing the charts (which is then linked to my word document where the charts are to be displayed). So after doing this I ran my script and to my annoyance, the data links between my openpyxl spreadsheet and charts spreadsheet had been severed. I guess this is because openpyxl creates a new spreadsheet when you save using the save function links are severed.

My question is.. are there any ways to maintain the data links?

Comment: Question changed to comply with rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to maintain links between files. I think it would be possible to keep them metadata but, for fairly obvious reasons, it won't necessarily be possible to validate them. This best way for this to happen would be through a pull request.

If you're on Windows you might look at using the Python for Windows stuff which will allow you to remote control the applications.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, i'm on OSX and want my script to run without relying on excel.

Comment: The best thing then is to help add support. Unfortunately, "relationships" are poorly defined in the specification and even more poorly implemented in openpyxl. Once that's been cleaned up it should be quite easy to support the sort of thing you want.